# AWS Elastic Load Balancer with HTTPS Listener. End-user browser seeing site as secure?

Tags: amazon-ec2, certificate, amazon-elb

I want to setup a classic “Elastic Load Balancer” (ELB) in Amazon Web Services (AWS) with a HTTPS listener.  This type of listener requires that you paste in private and public keys and a certificate chain.

For this question, let’s me refer to the above certificate files as private1.pem, public1.pem and certchain1.pem.
Certificate Authority #1 issued the certificate.

The application servers that will be behind this ELB will use a different private and public key and certificate chain files.  Let’s refer to them as private2.pem, public2.pem and certchain2.pem.
Certificate Authority #2 issued the certificate.

When a end-user makes a call to the main website URL, is it the certificates being referenced by the application servers that will decide whether the certificate are trusted by the end-users browser?  Is it correct to say, that if the end-users browser trusts the certificate authority that the application server certificates are approved by, that green pad-lock will show in end-users browser?  What if the end-user browser DOES NOT trust the certificate authority for the certificate files that are being used by the ELB?

Answer (score 0):

The browser will never see certificate installed on the server, in this configuration.  Only the certificate on the classic ELB itself will be seen.

If the browser doesn't trust that certificate, then it doesn't trust it.

The certificate on the server is only seen by the back side of the ELB, where it can be used to (1) re-encrypt the traffic between the back-side of the balancer and the instance if the balancer is configured to expect TLS between it and the instance and (2) optionally authenticate the instance to the balancer to verify so that the balancer can prove that no impostor instances are attached to the balancer -- which is, in practice, as unlikely as it sounds but sometimes needed for compliance or policy reasons. In the second case, you provide the balancer with a copy of the instance certificate and it will connect only to an instance that is in possession of that same certificate and the matching private key.  The back-end cert can be self-signed, since the trust is based on the fact that you gave the cert to the balancer for comparison, rather than the usual public trust chain mechanisms.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html